# type error saving lxml elements in shelve

Tags: python, lxml, pickle

I'm processing some xml files.
`pb_id` is a string.
`page_elements` is a list.

```
pb_id = x.xpath('//pb/@xml:id')[0]
page_elements = x.xpath('//@xml:id[preceding::pb]')
```

I want to save these values in a shelve cache:

```
s = shelve.open('cache.shelve')
s[str(pb_id)] = page_elements
```

But it returns this error:

> can't pickle _Element objects

Do I need to cast `page_elements` in some other type?
`type(page_elements)` is `<type 'list'>`

Comment: The problem is not the lists, it's the _Element-objects. And they are a C-based extension type, thus you can't pickle them. And Python knows no "casting". What you can do is to e.g. determine the actual path to the invididual elements as a sequence of indices to the children, coming from the root, and pickle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only picklable data types can be stored in a shelf -- in particular, types added by C extensions need explicit support to be picklable; lxml has not as of this date had that support written.

Unless you're willing to provide a patch to upstream lxml and shepherd it through merge and release, I'd suggest revisiting your requirements: Why are you trying to store the data in question? Can you serialize the content in a different way (say, to XML text -- even if that text is then shelved), and deserialize it on load?

If you encapsulate your XML elements inside a data structure you control, you can override `__getstate__()` and `__setstate__()` to serialize and deserialize appropriately; read [the pickle library documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) for details.

You might end up with something like this:

```
class PicklablePage(object):
  def __init__(self, page_elements=None):
    self.page_elements = page_elements or []
  def __getstate__(self):
    return {'page_elements': [ lxml.etree.tostring(el)
                               for el in self.page_elements ]}
  def __setstate__(self, state):
    self.page_elements = [ lxml.etree.fromstring(el_text)
                           for el_text in state['page_elements'] ]
```

This can then be pickled and unpickled (and thus shelved and unshelved) safely:

```
>>> el = lxml.etree.fromstring('<content>Hello</content>')
>>> p = PicklablePage([el])
>>> print pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(p)).page_elements[0].text
Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, understood: the list is made of _Element object.
i think i've solved this way, converting all list element to str()

```
 page_elements[:] = [str(x) for x in page_elements]
```

Comment: `str(x)` isn't the same as `lxml.etree.tostring(x)` -- it'll emit things like `<Element page at 0x7fc0f534ed88>`, which can't then be turned back into an element.

Comment: ...correct code for converting elements to and from strings is included in my answer (and _was_ included for a good 5 minutes before this answer was written); any particular reason it's unfit/unusable as-given?

Comment: your solution is clean and fit my needs, i'm using it right now, thanks.  but also str() works

Comment: Odd. I can't reproduce `str()` working the way it would need to -- I get the `<Element content at 0x7fc0f4eee6c8>` behavior -- but maybe we're running different versions.